# "Chat with an expert"

Tags: support

After visiting a question I had posted on this site a few months back, I had noticed something strange with this site.

In the bottom right corner appeared a black rectangle (respecting the general design of the site), that said "Chat with an expert".

I opened it up out of curiosity, and connected with the "expert" itself: just as I had expected, it was a bot.

What was exactly going on?

Wild guess: is Stackoverflow at it again? (As in, doing some tests with various AI algorithms, which had already happened before.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bot based on [ELIZA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA), as an April Fools' Day joke:

[What is "chat with an expert"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)

Comment: Oh snap, damn it

Comment: One more thing: I can notice that in all other SE sites *without logging into any* <-- which is somewhat *sheepish*. BTW, Someone have totally changed their name ;-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: Me? That was just temporary (and only on Physics), though I might permanently switch to muon later.

Comment: Yeah.. I noticed it. Muon is cool. (*A fast reply though*) ;-)